# Ping pong tournament organization

Tags: webapp-rec

I would like to organize a ping pong tournament in my company. Does someone know a webapp witch allow to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Konkuri**](http://www.konkuri.com/) seems to be doing just that, <del>but it seems to be only in french</del>.

The website is in french, but you can change the language by choosing your preferred culture in the footer (thanks neo).

Comment: It is available in a few other languages (just look at the footer).

Comment: perfect I'm french!!

Comment: @Neo thanks for pointing this out, I looked at a few standard places in the application for a way to change the language, but I couldn't find it.